# Deserialize xml received into C# object

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I am writing an application that will receive an XML packet.  I have tried creating an object in C# to deserialize the XML received to, and it works fine.  I have noticed that if the class name is not the same as the root element name in the XML packet, deserialization to that class will not work.  I have searched everywhere on the web for a simple application, do not even know if it is possible, but my question is: How do I automatically create a class in C# based on the XML packt received? is this possible? or something close to this scenario that I can work around for in case the root element name is different than the class name.  any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: you should look at xsd.exe it will help you create the classes automatically

Comment: not quite sure on how to use this. is it possible to use the xsd.exe in code without me having to do anything manual, except coding the necessary steps to use the xsd.exe?

Comment: not in your code... sorry to quickly create your objects so you don't have to manually code them...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the RootNode attribute in order to change the name?

```
[XmlRoot("RootNodeName")]
public class MyClass {...}
```

Based on your comment:

You cannot create a strongly typed class at runtime.

Have you looked into using **LINQ to XML** instead of XML serialization? This might better suit your (dynamic) needs. You can still keep your class, just fill it via LINQ to XML expressions instead of direct deserialization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: I cannot use the [XmlRoot("RootNodeName")] tag, since I will have no access to the XML packet.  As soon as it is received at the specified port, the processing begins.  Is there any other way?

Comment: I have thought of doing that, but that is a long and tiresome process.  Will that not affect the speed, or is speed not to be considered here?

Comment: @AndrewKemp I'm not sure which one is faster without running some tests. I've used both and have never seen a speed issue (for my cases). Unless you're talking about ridiculously huge files I don't believe it's a big consideration. But you should always assess your needs and not take my comments on blind faith.

Comment: I believe it is possible to use linq to xml to retrieve the root element name? if so, I will do that, and set the  [XmlRoot("RootNodeName")] equal to the result found.

Comment: You cannot, you can only pass a constant into it. But to answer your question: xDoc.Root.Name.ToString()

Comment: so even if I have a class called myHTTP_Listener that received the packet and had to deserialize it to the class called XML_Packet, using the xDoc.Root.Name.Tostring() in the myHTTP_Listener class, there is no way of in the XML_Packet class setting the [XmlRoot("RootNodeName")] tag equal to the result of xDoc.Root.Name.Tostring()?  apologies if this is redundant questions, just trying to figure out what I can do to achieve this.

Comment: To my knowledge I don't believe so. XML de/serialization assumes there is a predefined structure (IE: your class). I've never come across a way to dynamically change it like you're suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jay.  Really appreciated.  I have come to the solution to use linq to xml.